# Is there a better way to extract the X2 and Y2 values in the following code?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
thread_list = ['DWr','Idle','MulWr','Lock'] #List of thread algorithms required
Target_list = ['0','0','0','1'] #List of Target numbers
mem_coor = [10,215,35,215,60,215,85,215,210,215,235,215,260,215,285,215] #X & Y coordinates of found targets 10=X,215=Y
targ_1 = ['write-back','uncachable-high'] #List of Target types
count_dash_T_list = [0,1,2,3] #Count 

count_target = 0 #Target count

#For four interations go through the target list
for i in range(0,len(count_dash_T_list)):
    #print(i)
    target = Target_list[count_target]
    count_target += 1
    
    #for each value in target list check if value is 1 or 0 and check target type then map to correct mem_coor
    for i in targ_1:
        if (target == '0'):
            if (i == 'write-back'):
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
            elif (i == 'uncachable-high'):
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
        elif (target == '1'):
            if (i == 'write-back'):
                X2 = mem_coor[8]
                Y2 = mem_coor[9]
            elif (i == 'uncachable-high'):
                X2 = mem_coor[10]
                Y2 = mem_coor[11]
                                
    print(X2)
    print(Y2)
```

The code above is what I have tried so far and I'm not sure how I can improve to get the correct results. I am getting the following results

```
35,
215,
35,
215,
35,
215,
235,
215
```

and I am expecting

```
10,
215,
10,
215,
10,
215.
235,
215
```

My code is extracting the second target type for each iteration instead of the write-back when target = 0 and uncachable-high when target = 1. This is what I am expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that the inner loop is on a non-changing array. That means that X2 and Y2 will always be filled twice, once with `i='write-back'` and once for `i='uncachable-high'`.

Regarding your original question, using a dictionary to map between the target and the target type to a tuple with the expected X and Y will probably be much simpler.
For example-

```
map_target_to_x_and_y = {
    ('0', 'write-back'): (10,215),
    ('0', 'uncachable-high'): (35,215),
    ...
}
```

Then accessing it-

```
X, Y = map_target_to_x_and_y[(target, target_type)]
```

Comment: This implementation does not work for list i get the following error: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: So use a tuple for a key :)